# Listview not showing in react-native

Tags: react-native

i wrote some codes using react native listview. it rendered correctly and there weren't any errors at all; however, the listview isn't showing at all. can someone advise? below is my code. thank you very much

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Stylesheet, View, ListView, Text } from 'react-native';
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2});

class Listvieweg extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{
        title: 'Why is the sky blue?',
        author: 'George'
      }])
    }
  }

  renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {rowData.title}
      </Text>
      <Text>
        {rowData.author}
      </Text>
    </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          style={styles.list}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => this.renderRow(rowData)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  list: {
    flex: 1
  }
}

export default Listvieweg;
```

Comment: Your `ListView` has `flex:1` as style but your `View` returned from `renderRow` has no style. That might create a problem. When you provide a `flex` ratio to the `View` of `renderRow`, then the problem should disappear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4):

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ListView
      ....
    />
  </View>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! appreciate